# How to prevent two column text to overlay with minipage of entire pagewidth?

Tags: positioning, two-column

I have a two column latex document and at the beginning of each chapter, I want to manually insert a minipage which spans the two columns. Unfortunately, the text in the right column will always overlay with the minipage. How can I prevent that from happening?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

% minipage spanning entire width.
% how do I prevent the text below from overlaying into the minipage?
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
STARTMINIPAGE \lipsum[1] ENDMINIPAGE
\end{minipage}

% text across two columns. the right column wraps into the minipage.
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\memoir@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\memoir@makechapterhead{#1}\dochapterprolog}
\makeatother

\def\chapterprolog#1{\gdef\dochapterprolog{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\vspace{3\baselineskip}
  \fi\chapterprolog{}}}
```

You'll start a chapter by

```
\chapterprolog{What we want in the full width minipage}
\chapter{Chapter title}
```

The contents of the chapter prolog is reset to empty after usage, so if a chapter has no prolog nothing particular has to be done.

Adjust the `3\baselineskip` to what suits you.

(Note: this new version will work also in one column mode)

Comment: Can this be done without `memoir`?

Comment: @isomorphismes Yes, of course; I used `memoir` as a prefix just because the post was about this class. It should work also with `report` and `book`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to switch between `onecolumn` and `twocolumn` modes without ejecting the page. I'd  suggest using `multicol` package written specifically for this.

Comment: I don't want to keep switching back and forth. All of the text is two columns, I really only want one minipage at the beginning of each chapter which spans both columns.

Answer (score 1):

[The `\multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) has a second optional parameter for text that you want to span over all the columns before the multi columns begin.

Note that there seems to be some problem with using `\lipsum` here, but adding real text it seems to work.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[%
    \chapter{test}
    \hrule
    Place your single column text here. 
    It will go across the page and the two column 
    text will begin after this.
    \hrule
]

% text across two columns.
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```